# How does Swift ReferenceWritableKeyPath work with an Optional property?

Tags: swift, option-type, combine, swift-keypath

**Ground of Being**: It will help, before reading, to know that you cannot assign a UIImage to an image view outlet's `image` property through the keypath `\UIImageView.image`. Here's the property:

```
@IBOutlet weak var iv: UIImageView!
```

Now, will this compile?

```
    let im = UIImage()
    let kp = \UIImageView.image
    self.iv[keyPath:kp] = im // error
```

No!

> Value of optional type 'UIImage?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'UIImage'

Okay, now we're ready for the actual use case.

---

What I'm actually trying to understand is how the Combine framework `.assign` subscriber works behind the scenes. To experiment, I tried using my own Assign object. In my example, my publisher pipeline produces a UIImage object, and I assign it to the `image` property of a UIImageView property `self.iv`.

If we use the `.assign` method, this compiles and works:

```
URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
    .map {$0.data}
    .replaceError(with: Data())
    .compactMap { UIImage(data:$0) }
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
    .assign(to: \.image, on: self.iv)
    .store(in:&self.storage)
```

So, says I to myself, to see how this works, I'll remove the `.assign` and replace it with my own Assign object:

```
let pub = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
    .map {$0.data}
    .replaceError(with: Data())
    .compactMap { UIImage(data:$0) }
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)

let assign = Subscribers.Assign(object: self.iv, keyPath: \UIImageView.image)
pub.subscribe(assign) // error
// (and we will then wrap in AnyCancellable and store)
```

Blap! We can't do that, because `UIImageView.image` is an Optional UIImage, and my publisher produces a UIImage plain and simple.

I tried to work around this by unwrapping the Optional in the key path:

```
let assign = Subscribers.Assign(object: self.iv, keyPath: \UIImageView.image!)
pub.subscribe(assign)
```

Cool, that compiles. But it crashes at runtime, presumably because the image view's image is initially `nil`.

Now I can work around all of this just fine by adding a `map` to my pipeline that wraps the UIImage up in an Optional, so that all the types match correctly. But my question is, how does this *really* work? I mean, why don't I have to do that in the first code where I use `.assign`? Why am I able to specify the `.image` keypath there? There seems to be some trickery about how key paths work with Optional properties but I don't know what it is.

---

After some input from Martin R I realized that if we type `pub` explicitly as producing `UIImage?` we get the same effect as adding a `map` that wraps the UIImage in an Optional. So this compiles and works

```
let pub : AnyPublisher<UIImage?,Never> = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
    .map {$0.data}
    .replaceError(with: Data())
    .compactMap { UIImage(data:$0) }
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()

let assign = Subscribers.Assign(object: self.iv, keyPath: \UIImageView.image)
pub.subscribe(assign)
let any = AnyCancellable(assign)
any.store(in:&self.storage)
```

This still doesn't explain how the original `.assign` works. It appears that it is able to *push* the optionality of the type *up* the pipeline into the `.receive` operator. But I don't see how that is possible.

Comment: Just curious: What happens in your first code if `self.iv.image` is nil?

Comment: @MartinR It works fine. (In real life I go on to `.store` the AnyCancellable as you would expect, and the code downloads and shows the image just fine.) That's why I'm confused; I didn't discover there was an "issue" until I tried to tease apart what `.assign` is doing behind the scenes by supplying my own Assign subscriber, subscribing it, and promoting it to AnyCancellable (not shown).

Comment: @MartinR I'll add that to the q.

Comment: I have no experience with Combine so far, so I do not “expect” anything :) – But I noticed that the inferred type of `let pub = ...` is `Publishers.ReceiveOn<Publishers.CompactMap<Publishers.ReplaceError<Publishers.Map<URLSession.DataTaskPublisher, Data>>, UIImage>, DispatchQueue>`.  If you annotate it explicitly, but with `UIImage` replaced by `UIImage?` then the error goes away. That seems to be what the compiler infers in the first example from `.assign(to: \.image, on: self.iv)` since `self.iv.image` is an optional.

Comment: The error also goes away if you replace `compactMap` by `map` – does that make sense? I am not sure.

Comment: @MartinR If you break the chain at `receiveOn`, its output typed as UIImage. If you add `assign`, `receiveOn` output is typed as UIImage?. It is as if the `assign` is able to push the optionality _up_ the pipeline. I don't understand how it does that.

Comment: You are also right that if we `eraseToAnyPublisher` and type the `pub` generic explicitly as parameterizing UIImage? the whole problem goes away. I'll add that to the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You (Matt) probably know at least some of this already, but here are some facts for other readers:

- Swift infers types on one whole statement at a time, but not across statements.
- Swift allows type inference to automatically promote an object of type `T` to type `Optional<T>`, if necessary to make the statement type-check.
- Swift also allows type inference to automatically promote a closure of type `(A) -> B` to type `(A) -> B?`. In other words, this compiles:

  ```
    let a: (Data) -> UIImage? = { UIImage(data: $0) }
    let b: (Data) -> UIImage?? = a
  ```

  This came as a surprise to me. I discovered it while investigating your problem.

Now let's consider the use of `assign`:

```
let p0 = Just(Data())
    .compactMap { UIImage(data: $0) }
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
    .assign(to: \.image, on: self.iv)
```

Swift type-checks this entire statement simultaneously. Since `\UIImageView.image`'s `Value` type is `UIImage?`, and `self.iv`'s type is `UIImageView!`, Swift has to do two “automatic” things to make this statement type-check:

- It has to promote the closure `{ UIImage(data: $0) }` from type `(Data) -> UIImage?` to type `(Data) -> UIImage??` so that `compactMap` can strip off one level of `Optional` and make the `Output` type be `UIImage?`.
- It has to implicitly unwrap `iv`, because `Optional<UIImageView>` has no property named `image`, but `UIImageView` does.

These two actions let Swift type-check the statement successfully.

Now suppose we break it into three statements:

```
let p1 = Just(Data())
    .compactMap { UIImage(data: $0) }
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
let a1 = Subscribers.Assign(object: self.iv, keyPath: \.image)
p1.subscribe(a1)
```

Swift first type-checks the `let p1` statement. It has no need to promote the closure type, so it can deduce an `Output` type of `UIImage`.

Then Swift type-checks the `let a1` statement. It must implicitly unwrap `iv`, but there's no need for any `Optional` promotion. It deduces the `Input` type as `UIImage?` because that is the `Value` type of the key path.

Finally, Swift tries to type-check the `subscribe` statement. The `Output` type of `p1` is `UIImage`, and the `Input` type of `a1` is `UIImage?`. These are different, so Swift cannot type-check the statement successfully. Swift does not support `Optional` promotion of generic type parameters like `Input` and `Output`. So this doesn't compile.

We can make this type-check by forcing the `Output` type of `p1` to be `UIImage?`:

```
let p1: AnyPublisher<UIImage?, Never> = Just(Data())
    .compactMap { UIImage(data: $0) }
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
let a1 = Subscribers.Assign(object: self.iv, keyPath: \.image)
p1.subscribe(a1)
```

Here, we force Swift to promote the closure type. I used `eraseToAnyPublisher` because otherwise `p1`'s type is too ugly to spell out.

Since `Subscribers.Assign.init` is public, we can also use it directly to make Swift infer all the types:

```
let p2 = Just(Data())
    .compactMap { UIImage(data: $0) }
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
    .subscribe(Subscribers.Assign(object: self.iv, keyPath: \.image))
```

Swift type-checks this successfully. It is essentially the same as the statement that used `.assign` earlier. Note that it infers type `()` for `p2` because that's what `.subscribe` returns here.

---

Now, back to your keypath-based assignment:

```
class Thing {
    var iv: UIImageView! = UIImageView()

    func test() {
        let im = UIImage()
        let kp = \UIImageView.image
        self.iv[keyPath: kp] = im
    }
}
```

This doesn't compile, with the error `value of optional type 'UIImage?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'UIImage'`. I don't know why Swift can't compile this. It compiles if we explicitly convert `im` to `UIImage?`:

```
class Thing {
    var iv: UIImageView! = UIImageView()

    func test() {
        let im = UIImage()
        let kp = \UIImageView.image
        self.iv[keyPath: kp] = .some(im)
    }
}
```

It also compiles if we change the type of `iv` to `UIImageView?` and optionalize the assignment:

```
class Thing {
    var iv: UIImageView? = UIImageView()

    func test() {
        let im = UIImage()
        let kp = \UIImageView.image
        self.iv?[keyPath: kp] = im
    }
}
```

But it does not compile if we just force-unwrap the implicitly-unwrapped optional:

```
class Thing {
    var iv: UIImageView! = UIImageView()

    func test() {
        let im = UIImage()
        let kp = \UIImageView.image
        self.iv![keyPath: kp] = im
    }
}
```

And it does not compile if we just optionalize the assignment:

```
class Thing {
    var iv: UIImageView! = UIImageView()

    func test() {
        let im = UIImage()
        let kp = \UIImageView.image
        self.iv?[keyPath: kp] = im
    }
}
```

I think this might be a bug in the compiler.

Comment: I think the key statement here might be "Swift does not support Optional promotion of generic type parameters like Input and Output" That is exactly what it seemed to me _was_ happening, and I couldn't understand why it was happening when `.assign` hooked things up but not when I hooked things up. I think your "promote the _closure_" is the explanation I'm looking for.

Comment: The final four is parallel to (but not quite the same as?) what I worked out in this question's "sister" question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59653363/more-about-the-weird-behavior-of-referencewritablekeypath-with-an-optional-prope?noredirect=1&lq=1 I have in fact attached it to an existing bug report, https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-11184.

Comment: Yeah that looks like the same bug.

Comment: The same promotion works for an array. If my closure is of type `() -> Array<Int>` and I assign it where a function of type `() -> Array<Optional<Int>>` is expected, that is legal and the closure when executed now does in fact produce an array of optional Ints.