# More about the weird behavior of ReferenceWritableKeyPath with an Optional property

Tags: swift, option-type, swift-keypath

(I say "more" in my title because this question is an appendix to my [How does Swift ReferenceWritableKeyPath work with an Optional property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59637100/how-does-swift-referencewritablekeypath-work-with-an-optional-property).)

In my code, `self.iv` is an outlet property:

```
@IBOutlet weak var iv: UIImageView!
```

Now, will this compile?

```
    let im = UIImage()
    let kp = \UIImageView.image
    self.iv[keyPath:kp] = im // error
```

No! We are told that something here must be unwrapped, although it is not entirely obvious what it is:

> Value of optional type 'UIImage?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'UIImage'

But now watch this. Instead of an outlet, I'll just *make* an image view:

```
    let im = UIImage()
    let kp = \UIImageView.image
    let iv = UIImageView()
    iv[keyPath:kp] = im
```

That compiles! Why? What semantic / syntactic difference is there between a UIImageView property and a UIImageView local? Is it that the property is an implicitly unwrapped Optional?

To test that idea, let's "propagate" the unwrapping of `self.iv` *explicitly* through a local:

```
    let im = UIImage()
    let kp = \UIImageView.image
    let iv = self.iv!
    iv[keyPath:kp] = im
```

That compiles too! But we *must* use a separate local; merely unwrapping `self.iv` directly is not sufficient:

```
    let im = UIImage()
    let kp = \UIImageView.image
    self.iv![keyPath:kp] = im // error
```

I am not understanding this at all. It goes against my standard beliefs about what an implicitly unwrapped Optional is, and about how a non-Optional may always be assigned to an Optional wrapping the same type. Something about ReferenceWritableKeyPath seems to work oddly with Optional properties but I can't put my finger on it.

So my question is (sorry, maybe a bit vague): can someone justify all these results and make them seem rational and predictable? What are the rules here?

**NOTE:** Could be the same as https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-11184

Comment: Here's some more weird stuff.  If you add the `!` to the keyPath it works: `let kp = \UIImageView.image!`.  This also works `self.iv[keyPath: kp]! = im`.

Comment: This compiles as well: `self.iv[keyPath: kp] = Optional(im)`.

Comment: Yes but first one crashes when original image turns out to be nil.